# cakephp ip addess returning 1 instead of ip address

Tags: logging, cakephp, ip

I am doing some simple logging on cakephp and I wanted to log the ip address of the client. I used the code to getthe IP address.

```
 $ip = $this->request->clientIp();
```

However, this is just returning ::1 instead of the actual IP address...

Comment: `::1` is an actual IP address, it's the IPv6 equivalent of `127.0.0.1`. Maybe you're testing on localhost, or your server is behind some sort of proxy that doesn't automatically pass on the visitors IP address, etc...

Comment: I am testing on localhost and did not know that haha thanks